# How to port C# code which uses a callback to VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to port the following from the [ASP.NET MVC 2 sourcecode](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) from C# to VB.NET.  It's from *AuthorizeAttribute.cs* beginning on line 86:

```
HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
```

where *CacheValidateHandler* is:

```
private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, 
                                  ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus) {
     validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
}
```

The VB.NET port from http://converter.telerik.com doesn't quite work for this line:

```
cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, Nothing) ' Error
```

where *CacheValidateHandler* is:

```
Private Sub CacheValidateHandler(ByVal context As HttpContext, ByVal data As Object, _
                                 ByRef validationStatus As HttpValidationStatus)
    validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(New HttpContextWrapper(context))
End Sub
```

VS2008 complains that *CacheValidateHandler* does not specify its arguments for *context*, *data*, and *validationStatus*.

Any ideas how to port this code?

Comment: a tip this converter does a great job converting c# to vb.net and the other way around.  

http://www.dotnetspider.com/Convert/Vb-To-Csharp.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing functions as arguments in VB.NET, you have to use the AddressOf keyword:

```
cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(AddressOf CacheValidateHandler, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.  Your answer was 5 seconds ahead of the next one, so I'll give you the green check.

Comment: I don't know why the Telerik converter didn't insert that.  I guess the translators aren't perfect.

Comment: @Bob : Actually, he was 55 seconds ahead of me.

I've recently used the Telerik converter as well. I don't think it actually looks your functions up (often it can't, if the function is in a different file). Also, when translating from VB.NET to C#, it translates indexed attributes incorrectly as array(0) rather than array[0].

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use [`AddressOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b(VS.80).aspx):

```
cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(AddressOf CacheValidateHandler, Nothing)
```